# How to prevent selection of a TabPage unless another TabPage's criteria are satisfied?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Form1 which has a [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx). There are 2 [TabPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage.aspx) within `tabControl1` , namely `tabpage1` and `tabpage` 2 . I would like to know if its possible to disable the selection of  `tabpage2` unless  all criteria of `tabpage1` are satisfied .

I do not see any enable or visible properties for each individual tabpage .

Comment: disable tabpage2 by default. Require a postback to the server for validation on tabpage1. if isValid, enable tabpage2. You can do the postback asynchronously so the user doesn't see the postback.

Comment: Here's some information to get you going - http://asplib.net/docs/asplib/TabStrip_ValGroup.html

Comment: I apologize .. I forgot to mention that I am writing a desktop application . I will edit question likewise .

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF?

Comment: [MSDN: How to: Disable Tab Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/252t3cec.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into the [TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event, or in some cases its better to hook into the [TabControl.Selecting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selecting.aspx) event.

Then in the event validate the criteria you have for the tab you are on, if it is good, then you're fine, if it isn't complete/invalid, then you can Cancel the tab change(using the e.Cancel for instance from the Selecting event, see example on linked page) from these events, putting you right back where you were and hopefully with a messagebox or something to show the user what is wrong with the input.